# Color rows by matching associations in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

My goal is to have rows where the loop results that have matching attributes have the same color background

Here is my attempt:

**controller:**

```
vendor_products = VendorProduct.where(vendor_id: current_user.id)
@vendor_orders = Order.where(product_id: vendor_products.map { |vp| vp.product_id}).order(created_at: :desc)
```

**Form:**

```
  <% @vendor_orders.each do |order, cart_id| %>
      <tr class="ok">
        <% if order.cart_id.present? && order.cart_id == order.cart_id %>
            <td><%= order.id %></td>
            <td><%= order.cart_id %></td>
            .....
        <% else %>
            <td><%= order.id %></td>
            <td><%= order.cart_id %></td>
            .....
        <% end %>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
```

(tried `if` statement both inside/outside `<tr>`)

**Style:**

```
.ok:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}

.ok:nth-child(even) {
  background: blue;
}
```

My goal is if the cart_id of the order match, then for the x number of orders matching cart_id's to have the same color background so it's known they are the same cart.

**Example:**

```
ID | Cart 

1  | 1 (red)

2  | 1 (red)

3  | nil

4  | 2 (blue)

5  | 2 (blue)
```

So, ID 1 and 2 would have their rows as red and ID 4 and 5 would have their rows as blue.  With 3 having no color since is doesn't belong to any cart.  Also, would like this for only carts that have multiple items.

Some orders will have no cart and only have one product associated with them.  Some order are created with a cart that will have multiple line items.

so basically, IF an orders cart_id is present? and the cart.line_items.count > 1, to have all the orders associated with it the same color.

**Models:**

```
**cart**

has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
has_one :order
...

**line items**

belongs_to :cart
...

**order**

belongs_to :cart
```

What my attempt does is nothing.  All the results just turn red.

I am tagging JS and JQ just in case because I assume that is a viable option for this to work.

Comment: Are you aware that the `if` branch and the `else` branch of your conditional are identical?

Comment: I want to display all records, even `if (order.cart_id == order.cart_id) == false`.

Comment: Either way, that's just one of many attempts.  No need to show other attempts because none work the way I would like unfortunately.  I've done that any many iterations of that, etc.

Comment: But `order.card_id == order.cart_id` must always be true.

Comment: Hm... how can I accomplish what i want then? I thought that would compare all value results

Comment: Your spec is not very clear. Will `cart_id` 1 always be red, and `cart_id` 2 always be blue? Or will the first cart always be red and the second cart always be blue, regardless of the `cart_id`? How many possible carts might there be in a single order? If more than two, how will you determine what color the third cart gets?

Comment: try plucking all the cart_ids from `@vendor_orders` and create a hash, with cart_id as key and random hex color as values. then while looping you call the style inline and call the color with cart_id as key.

Comment: @moveson it should iterate between red and blue.  The reason for 2 different colors is to differentiate between the groups of orders with the same cart_id, so 4 orders next to each other with 2 different carts will be able to be differentiate each other.  Basically, it's a visual thing.  Instead of needing to look at "cart_id" to know if 2 "orders" share the same cart, we will be able to have a visual color. Then use 2 colors so they aren't mixed together to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need some specialized logic that belongs neither in the view nor in the controller. I would suggest you place this logic into a presenter.

The controller logic is dead simple:

```
# app/controllers/orders_controller.rb

class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @presenter = VendorOrderPresenter.new(current_user&.id)
  end
end
```

The specialized logic is contained in a presenter:

```
# app/presenters/vendor_order_presenter.rb

class VendorOrderPresenter
  COLORS = %w[red blue].freeze

  def initialize(current_user_id)
    @current_user_id = current_user_id
  end

  def vendor_orders
    @vendor_orders ||= Order.where(product_id: vendor_products.pluck(:product_id)).order(created_at: :desc)
  end

  def completed_orders
    @completed_orders ||= vendor_orders.where(order_status: "complete")
  end

  def background_color(order)
    index = colorable_cart_ids.index(order.cart_id)
    index ? COLORS[index % COLORS.size] : nil
  end

  private

  attr_reader :current_user_id

  def vendor_products
    VendorProduct.where(vendor_id: current_user_id)
  end

  def colorable_cart_ids
    @colorable_cart_ids ||= cart_ids.select { |id| cart_ids.count(id) > 1 }.uniq
  end

  def cart_ids
    @cart_ids ||= vendor_orders.pluck(:cart_id).compact
  end
end
```

Now the view layer is simple and intuitive with no conditional or specialized logic:

```
# app/views/orders/index.html.erb

<h1>Index</h1>
<table>
  <thead>
  <th>Order ID</th>
  <th>Cart ID</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <% @presenter.vendor_orders.each do |order| %>
    <tr style='background:<%= @presenter.background_color(order) %>'>
      <td><%= order.id %></td>
      <td><%= order.cart_id %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

A full working solution can be found [here](https://github.com/moveson/order-row-colors).

Comment: You should change `% 2` to `% COLORS.size`. It’s more flexible and gets rid of magic numbers.

Comment: You went off   .   I know you say this is dead simple but it's a bit over my head.  Say I wanted to add a column for `Orders.where(order_status: "complete" )`, would I try to add that to the VendorOrderPresnter or would I make a new presenter file?

Comment: You can use the same presenter. Just add a public method and define it. See my edited answer. You can address the new method with `@presenter.completed_orders`.

Comment: perfect.  one more issue is that not all orders will have a cart_id and orders without that aren't appearing.  How can I tweak the presenter to allow all orders to go through, even if cart_id doesn't appear.  Basically an Order will either have cart_id or shop_order_id

Comment: omg, I had the `if cart.present` still in the view lol wow.  nvm.. thanks for everything

Answer (score 0):

This is a suggestion. I compiled and served the same purpose.

in your controller pluck the cart ids from `@vendor_orders` and make a hash with the id as key and random color as value.

```
    @ids = @vendor_orders.pluck(:id)
    @ids = @ids.uniq
    @color = Hash.new
    @ids.each do |val|
        @color["#{val}"] = "##{random_hex}"
    end
```

where random_hex is

```
def random_hex
    colour = "%06x" % (rand * 0xffffff)
    return colour
end
```

now in your view inside loop call the color respective to cart_id from `@color` like

`<td style='background:<%= @color["#{order.cart_id}"] %>'><%= order.cart_id %></td>`

Comment: Okay this works thank. How can I specify the list of colors I would like to use instead of random? So it iterates between "red" and "blue"

Comment: This actually doesn't work for a number of reasons. The color is based on the id of the vendor_order, not the id of the cart. And it doesn't distinguish whether the cart has multiple items or not.

Comment: @uno what if there is more than two ids

Comment: As long as it iterates that is fine. I just don't want the same color next to each other.  Basically, I just want the color as a visual aid instead of needing to read the cart_id column to see if they share the same cart.